# Old icons list of Fontawesome

Tags: html, css

Fontawesome is now upgraded to version 5, but many our apps are still in old version. How can I find old version icon's with their `content` (CSS property) list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to the Icons page. Then click Free from the upper left hand corner.

Here: [FontAwesome Icon page](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free)

EDIT:

### Found it!

It was there on the frontpage all along. Under the Check out Pro -button.

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/

Comment: Yes there are old icons, but what if we need old icons content (CSS Property) code for example "\f00d"

Comment: @saadeez If you are Icons Page, click Free from the upper left hand corner and then click "Information" icon on the right side (where you can change page layout) Now you should see CSS property like you asked.

Answer (score -2):

visit below link
https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=search&m=free and click on top left "Free" link, after that you can see all free icons and it's name. Above that you can see the search box. Now you can search your icon from it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GLJz.png)